# Last row of AddIn worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I've created an AddIn and need to reference the last cell in column A.  I do this all the time in regular macros but having a time with it in the AddIn.

I've tried

```
lRow2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Client").Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
```

and

```
lRow2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
```

even

```
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim lRow2 As Long

Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Client")

With ws2
    lRow2 = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

which only returns a value of 1 which is not correct.

I've read that I have to use `ThisWorkbook` to refer to the AddIn worksheet but I either get subscript out of range or object doesn't support this methods in the various way I've tried to write this out.

Comment: FYI, you use `ThisWorkbook` to refer to the workbook containing the code that is running. If this code is not in the add-in, then you wouldn't get the results you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I was close.  This retrieves the correct last row number for the addin worksheet

```
With Workbooks("Book1.xlam").Sheets("Sheet1")

lRow = Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count

End With
```

Comment: This will not give you the last row of `Workbooks("Book1.xlam").Sheets("Sheet1")` unless it is the activesheet. You need to add `.` before the range and other objects

Comment: I thought so to but it worked at the time.  Coming back to it today I realize that only worked because I had the actual workbook open.  Now trying to figure out how to reference the values in the worksheet of the addin without the addin workbook actually being open.